# Python turtle drawing glitch?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, grid-layout, python-turtle, visual-glitch

I wanted to create a type of "grid" using turtle in python but when I start the program the parts of the drawing had a sort of broken line like this:
[Glitchy part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG6Xo.png)

This is the full image:
[Full drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1XX6.png)

I don't know is this a glitch or something wrong in my code but this is what I did:

```
for column in range(5):
    penup()
    goto(-207.5, (325 - (column * 110)))
    color('darkgray')
    begin_fill()
    for row in range(5):
        pendown()
        for square in range(4):
        forward(75)
        right(90)
    penup()
    forward(85)
    end_fill()
```

This program is drawing 5 cubes in a column and the whole drawing has 5 colums. My problem is that certant cubes get drawn wrong like I showed in first image and usualy the first row is drawn completly wrong(with broken lines in cubes) like in second image.
Is this a glitch or did I do something wrong? Can I fix it? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure! I just edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be -207.5. Make that a whole number.

I also removed some redundant code such as drawing the same square 5 times and used instance mode instead of the error-prone `from turtle import *` wildcard import that pollutes the namespace.

```py
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


t = Turtle()
t.color("darkgray")
t.penup()

for column in range(5):
    t.goto(-207, 325 - column * 110)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(4):
        t.forward(75)
        t.right(90)

    t.penup()
    t.end_fill()

Screen().exitonclick()
```